# How to add Linkify.WEB_URLS and JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD at content?

Tags: java, android, justify, linkify

I can add Linkify style for my code. It works.
I can set JustificationMode. It works.
But if I use both of them, Linkify style is used without JustificationMode. Pls help.

```
'''
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            tv.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
        }
        Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
'''
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same

Comment: No, I didn't =(